# Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I've installed ODAC 12c R3 Beta2, VS2013 Update 4, .net 4.5.2 and Entity Framework 6.1.2 Beta to test EF6 Code-first feature with Oracle Database. But the error is occurred and don't know what to do.

Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
on var db = new BloggingContext() line.

Here is a piece of code i run and app.config i used.

```html
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BloggingContext())
            {
                // Create and save a new Blog 
                Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();

                var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                var query = from b in db.Blogs
                            orderby b.Name
                            select b;

                Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            } 
        }

        public class Blog
        {
            public int BlogId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        }

        public class Post
        {
            public int PostId { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }

            public int BlogId { get; set; }
            public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
        }

        public class BloggingContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        }
```

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=_________;Password=__________;Data Source=_________" />
  </connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same trouble and I resolved this way:
First uninstall any nuget packet giving you any Oracle provider, you won't need them. Then right click on "References" in your Solution and then "Add Reference..." and add both this two:

**Path_to_ODAC_installation\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
Path_to_ODAC_installation\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\EF6\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll**

(I think you should clean and rebuild here)

then into your web.config use this as provider

```
<providers>
<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</providers>
```

and comment out your "Default" connection string.
Last but not the least, go into your **Path_to_ODAC_installation\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora** and check if it has the right connection parameters.

Finally return to Visual Studio, right click on Models, "Add", "New Item", "Data", "ADO.Net Entity Data Model", "Code First from Database". Here create a New Connection with your user name and password to access Oracle Database, Connection Type => "TNS" and use the tns you modified a step ago. Test your connection and save it ("Yes, include the sensitive data in the connection string").

Here i suppose for the sake of example you named your connection string "Model1". So, where you declared BloggingContext, use this constructor

```
public BloggingContext():base("Model1")
{
}
```

Comment: Changed "Version=6.121.2.0" to "Version=6.121.1.0" and its done :p